# PHP Bash Script Executed in Browser

Tags: php, shell, command-line-interface

I have written a bash script to call with shell_exec() and it has to be done only in that way. However, both bash and browser execute the script. I'm trying to figure it out what I missed.

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
    require_once '../classpath.php';
    require_once LIB_PATH.'Parser.php';
    require_once LIB_PATH.'Save.php';
    include FUNCTION_PATH.'multi_download.php';

    $save = new Save();
    $save->setFolder(CACHE_VIDEO_PATH);

    $parser = new Parser($argv[1]);
    $basename = $parser->bytag('/cast/stream/video/','.ts')[1];
    array_shift($basename);
    for($i= 0;$i<sizeof($basename);$i++){
        //echo CACHE_VIDEO_PATH.'/'.$basename[$i].'.ts';
        if(!$save->checkFile(CACHE_VIDEO_PATH.'/'.$basename[$i].'.ts'))
            $basename[$i] = SERVER_URL.$basename[$i].'.ts';
        else
            array_splice($basename,$i,$i);
    }
```

Comment: What is your issue? What is your question?

Comment: I don't want that script to be executed via browser. It seems I should check php_sapi_name().

Comment: If you can execute it via browser, you should remove the file from public directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

    /* If it is not cli mode, do not execute the rest */
    if (!php_sapi_name() == "cli")
        die();

    require_once '../classpath.php';
    require_once LIB_PATH.'Parser.php';
    require_once LIB_PATH.'Save.php';
    include FUNCTION_PATH.'multi_download.php';

    $save = new Save();
    $save->setFolder(CACHE_VIDEO_PATH);

    $parser = new Parser($argv[1]);
    $basename = $parser->bytag('/cast/stream/video/','.ts')[1];
    array_shift($basename);
    for($i= 0;$i<sizeof($basename);$i++){
        //echo CACHE_VIDEO_PATH.'/'.$basename[$i].'.ts';
        if(!$save->checkFile(CACHE_VIDEO_PATH.'/'.$basename[$i].'.ts'))
            $basename[$i] = SERVER_URL.$basename[$i].'.ts';
        else
            array_splice($basename,$i,$i);
    }
```

Please do research before ask a question, you may want to read about php cli.
[PHP Bash Script Executed in Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296758/php-bash-script-executed-in-browser)

Comment: I haven't heard anything like that, thats because I couldn't search. Thanks a lot.